# Formate numeric (decimal) value into dates

Tags: r

I have a df with a column of the formate `df$date = (1800.01, 1800.02, 1800.03)` and so on.
And I can't figure out how to convert these numbers into proper monthly dates.

I tried the function `date_decimal` from the `lubridate` package, but that does not work for how my dates are formated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `as.Date(paste0(df$date, ".01"), "%Y.%m.%d")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way is to convert to a character first, then use one of the standard conversion functions. e.g.:

```
lubridate::ym(as.character(df$date))
```